# How to fix 100% HDD usage in intel optane memory based laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

My laptop's harddisk usage is at 100% without any activity.
Task manager display active time as 100%
read speed -0 kbps and write speed 0 kbps.

How I fix this problem?

My laptop's specifications

- CPU - intel core i5-8250 U 1.60Ghz
- Ram - 8GB + intel Optane memory
- 16GB HDD - 1TB Toshiba

This is the link to screen shot of the task manager
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7skiI.png

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from some process, here is how to find it:

- Start Task Manager
- Details tab
- Right-click the headers and click on "Select columns"
- Place a check-mark next to "I/O reads" and "I/O writes"
- Click on either header to sort in descending order
- Find the process whose numbers are rapidly increasing.

Once the process is found, report which one is it, so we can go on fixing
the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Hard disk platters was damaged and I replace it with the new **NVMe SSD** and **remove the optane memory**.